# How do you successfully setup SSH so you can connect to the same host from two different clients?

Tags: ssh, openssh, ssh-keys, sshd

There are a lot of posts about this type of stuff but I haven't been able to find an answer that works for me...

I have an SSH server setup on a Ubuntu machine at home. I was able to setup no password authentication using private/public keys on one machine and it works. However when I try to add a second client to it in a similar manner, the client is getting denied. The first machine is still able to SSH in. Below is the main info:

---

On the 2nd client I'm getting the error: `clientPC@localIP: Permission denied (publickey).`

I created the keys on each client machine using command: `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096`

The host Linux PC has 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys and 700 on ~/.ssh for permissions.

The authorized_keys file has the 2 key blocks and they appear to be separated by a newline, starting with 'ssh-rsa' and ending with the host name. I appended the new key using `cat ~/.ssh/2nd_machine_key.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

The /var/log/auth.log shows: `sshd[25266]: Connection reset by authenticating user hostLinuxMachine 192.168.0.29 port 53900 [preauth]`

My sshd_config file is copied here:
https://pastebin.com/Q6s4sTwU

Comment: Try just using the same key on each client.

Comment: @mully it does work when I do that. I was hoping I could make separate private keys work however. Thank you :)

Comment: @NickGreen It *should* work with separate keys as well. As far as I can see the problem pretty much has to be something to do with how the two keys are stored in the `authorized_keys` file, but without access to the file itself I can only speculate. I'd try printing the file with `LC_ALL=C cat -vet ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` and looking for any differences between how the two keys are stored (note: that command should add a `$` to the end of each line, but otherwise not change how the lines look; if it *does* change something else... that indicates a potential problem).

Comment: Have you tried using `ssh-copy-id` instead of manually editing  `authorized_keys` ? Most likely you are running into some ediing artifacts

Comment: @EugenRieck I haven't used ssh-copy-id as I'm copying over from a windows machine. I'll look at this again tomorrow and try what Gordan suggests as well. Thank you all!

Comment: If it's coming from Windows, it may be in the DOS/Windows text format, which is just different enough from Unix format to cause all sorts of weird problems. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings).

Comment: Interesting. The keys appear to be stored the same. They both have the ^M carriage return at the end followed by $ and both start with ssh-rsa

Comment: It works now that I recreated the private key on client 2 but I don't know why. I did run dos2unix on the authorized key file but that was before I even pasted the new private key into the file. Don't like these types of resolutions :P